# Simplify SQL by nesting

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I have to copy and the following code into SQL developer and then copay & paste the results. How can I nest the following SQL to make life easier?

`Select * from ir.application where application_number = 'xxxxxxxxxx';`

Transpose xxxxxxxxxx with actual application number
Run this statement. Copy below SQL

```
--application ID = aaaaaaa
--aaaaaaa
```

Transpose --aaaaaaa with ID number by highlighting and hitting CTRL + C
Copy and paste the following SQL into SQL Developer

`select * from document where app_id = aaaaaaa;`

Copy the ID result into the SQL code transposing "aaaaaaa" with the result from above

Hit Run

Copy and paste the following SQL into SQL Developer

```
--document ID = ddddddd
--ddddddd
```

Transpose --ddddddd with ID number by highlighting and hitting CTRL + C
Copy and paste the following into SQL Developer

```
--aaaaaaa = application ID from 1st query
--ddddddd = document ID from 2nd query
update ir.application set application_number = null where id = aaaaaaa;
update ir.application set ttl_id = null where id = aaaaaaa;
update document set app_id = null where id = ddddddd;
update document set title_number = null where id = ddddddd;
update document set case_number = null where id = ddddddd;
commit;
```

Transpose as appropriate
Now Run each line in turn from "update..." down to "commit;" by highlighting and hitting Run after each semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've massively over-complicated your sql. For a start, you can update multiple columns in an update statement, so there's no need to have an update statement per column.

I think you just need two statements:

```
update ir.application
set    application_number = null,
       ttl_id = null
where  application_number = :app_num;

update document
set    app_id = null,
       title_number = null,
       case_number = null
where app_id = (select app_id from ir.application where application_number = :app_num);

commit;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. 2 quick questions, is `:app_num` the xxxxxxx from the original? and do I still need the `commit` at the end of either statement?

Comment: 1) Yes - you should end up with a prompt to populate it when you run the sql. I use Toad, but I think SQL Developer should work similarly. 2) Yes, if you want your changes to be saved into the database for other users to see! This is assuming that all rows for the application need to be updated. You mentioned document id in your original script; I'm assuming that if you had multiple document ids that you'd run the update for each of them? If not, how did you decide which document id to use? Whatever that logic is, you'd have to include in the above update statements in place of the app_id.